# C# Campo decimal aceitar valor igual ou maior que 0 na validação

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou com problema nas validações dos meus campos do tipo `decimal` utilizando o Razor, quando tento inserir 0 no campo ele da a seguinte mensagem de erro.

> The field XXXX must be a number.

Segue abaixo o meu a minha classe e o como insiro o campo com o Razor

```
public class ClasseViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatorio")]
    [Display(Name = "Campo Decimal")]
    public decimal? CampoDecimal { get; set; }
}
```

Razor:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CampoDecimal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CampoDecimal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CampoDecimal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Como faria para que a validação de se o campo é numérico ou não aceitasse o valor 0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256753/min-max-value-validators-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: se é obrigatório, porque colocar um campo que pode ser null ? `decimal?`

Comment: no caso é pq ele a principio vem nulo, porém nessa tela ele é obrigado a informa-lo

Comment: Acabei de gerar um teste só pra verificar isso do jeito que você elaborou e não tive problemas em gravar Zero, estranho de mais, essa classe só tem esses campos, será que não é outro campo?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic acabei de fazer o teste num projeto novo e realmente passou, provavelmente foi alguma coisa q sobrescreveram no projeto q estou utilizando, vc sabe onde faz essas validações ara eu verificar se algo foi sobrescrito? Acredito q talvez possa ter até sido o arquivo de js?

Comment: Olha na pasta Scripts tem os arquivos validation são eles que são responsaveis para tal, se você sobrepor com esse dos novos se poderia testar se realmente são eles!

Answer (score 3):

Já que está tudo com Razor, use `DataAnnotations` para colocar o limite de 1 par o infinito (pode ser outro numero) e remova `?` se o parametro é required

```
[Range(1, Double.PositiveInfinity)]
public decimal CampoDecimal { get; set; }
```

Para maior detalhes: [data annotations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6)

Comment: Não funciona, quero usar com o valor 0 e já usei essa validação antes e mesma assim a validação anterior continua